# Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage

I have divs on my site, when I click one, a textbox appears unique to that div. When I press the Add Item button that's supposed save the text, it gives me an error on the addListItem function:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Here are some of my functions regarding this case:

```
// Add a new list item
    function addListItem(shapeId) {
      const shape = $(`#${shapeId}`);
      const shapeInfo = shape.data("info");
      if (shapeInfo) {
        const shapeInput = shape.find(".shape-input");
        const newItem = shapeInput.val();
        if (newItem.trim() !== "") {
          if (!shapeInfo.items) {
            shapeInfo.items = [];
          }
          shapeInfo.items.push(newItem);
          shapeInput.val("");
          populateShapeList(shape);
          saveShapeData();
        }
      }
    }

    // Function to save shape data to local storage
    function saveShapeData() {
      const shapesData = [];
      $(".shape").each(function() {
        const shapeId = $(this).attr("id");
        const shapeData = {
          id: shapeId,
          top: $(this).position().top,
          left: $(this).position().left,
          width: $(this).width(),
          height: $(this).height(),
          items: $(this).data("info") ? $(this).data("info").items : []
        };
        shapesData.push(shapeData);
      });
      localStorage.setItem("shapes", JSON.stringify(shapesData));
    }
```

The code is not entirely mine, as far as I'm aware, the part with the trim function is trying to decide whether or not the input is empty, but the problem seems to appear there. Please correct me if I'm wrong, I'm no expert.

Comment: The problem doesn't really have anything to do with `localStorage`, or with most of the code shown.  The error implies that `shape.find(".shape-input")` didn't find any matching element.  Now is the time for you to do some debugging.  When `addListItem` is called and the problem occurs, what is the value of `shapeId`?  What does `$(`#${shapeId}`)` find?  What does `shape.find(".shape-input")` find?  What value are you expecting from it and why?  Can you create a runnable [mcve] which focuses specifically on these operations and demonstrates the problem?

Comment: That means that the value of `newItem` is `undefined`, at the very least you should change `newItem.trim() !== ""` to something like `newItem && newItem.trim() !== ""` But i would recommend you check more as I don't know what value/type you would be expecting from `.val()`

Comment: `const shapeInput = shape.find(".shape-input");`  where shape is `const shape = $(`#${shapeId}`);` a node element... maybe `const shapeInput = shape.querySelector(".shape-input");`  ?

Comment: How are you calling `addListItem`?

Comment: @GrafiCode jQuery functions don't return DOM elements, they return jQuery collections. `shape` is a jQuery collection, and the jQuery `find()` method is correct (otherwise the error would say that `find()` doesn't exist).

Comment: @Barmar and it allows to find an element within passing the class selector as a parameter? `const shapeInput = shape.find(".shape-input");` Ah, https://api.jquery.com/find/ now I see that

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add a new list item
function addListItem(shapeId) {
  const shape = $(`#${shapeId}`);
  const shapeInfo = shape.data("info");
  if (shapeInfo) {
    const shapeInput = shape.find(".shape-input");
    const newItem = shapeInput.val();
    if (newItem && newItem.trim() !== "") {
      if (!shapeInfo.items) {
        shapeInfo.items = [];
      }
      shapeInfo.items.push(newItem);
      shapeInput.val("");
      populateShapeList(shape);
      saveShapeData();
    }
  }
}

// Function to save shape data to local storage
function saveShapeData() {
  const shapesData = [];
  $(".shape").each(function() {
    const shapeId = $(this).attr("id");
    const shapeData = {
      id: shapeId,
      top: $(this).position().top,
      left: $(this).position().left,
      width: $(this).width(),
      height: $(this).height(),
      items: $(this).data("info") ? $(this).data("info").items : []
    };
    shapesData.push(shapeData);
  });
  localStorage.setItem("shapes", JSON.stringify(shapesData));
}
```

i think the issue was sometimes newItem getting undefined that why u are getting error.
just check one condition like if (newItem && newItem.trim() !== "") this time it will check first newItem is there then only it will exicute the next one.
try the updated code.i hope it will work..

Answer (score 0):

The following example will generate a random shape and add it to the shapes in local storage.

When rendering, the shapes will be retrieved from local storage.

Separating your code into modular functions may help with readability and maintainability. I created a function for transforming a shape object into an element, and another one that does the opposite.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>jQuery + localStorage</title>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"
      integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    ></script>
    <style>
      *,
      *:before,
      *:after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      html,
      body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        gap: 1rem;
        padding: 1rem;
      }
      .shape-list {
        position: relative;
        background: #ddd;
        flex: 1;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .shape {
        position: absolute;
        border: thin solid red;
      }
      .actions {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 0.5rem;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        populateShapeList();

        $('form[name="add-shape"]')
          .find('[name="shape"]')
          .val(JSON.stringify(randomShape(), null, 2));

        $('form[name="add-shape"]').on("submit", (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          addListItem($(e.target).find('[name="shape"]'));
        });

        $("#clear-btn").on("click", (e) => {
          const $input = $(e.target).closest("form").find('[name="shape"]');
          clearShapes();
          populateShapeList();
          $input.val(JSON.stringify(randomShape(), null, 2));
        });
      });

      // Add a new list item
      function addListItem($input) {
        const shape = $input.val();
        if (shape.trim().length > 0) {
          saveShape(JSON.parse(shape));
          populateShapeList();
          $input.val(JSON.stringify(randomShape(), null, 2));
        }
      }

      function populateShapeList($shape) {
        $(".shape-list").empty().append(restoreShapes().map(fromObject));
      }

      function randomShape() {
        const $shapeList = $(".shape-list");
        const maxWidth = $shapeList.outerWidth();
        const maxHeight = $shapeList.outerHeight();
        let top = randInt(0, maxHeight);
        let left = randInt(0, maxWidth);
        const width = randInt(10, 300);
        const height = randInt(10, 300);
        if (top + height > maxHeight) {
          top -= maxHeight - height; // Nudge up
        }
        if (left + width > maxWidth) {
          left -= maxWidth - width; // Nudge left
        }
        return {
          id: `box${restoreShapes().length + 1}`,
          top: top,
          left: left,
          width: width,
          height: height,
          items: [],
        };
      }

      function toObject($shape) {
        return {
          id: $shape.attr("id"),
          top: $shape.position().top,
          left: $shape.position().left,
          width: $shape.width(),
          height: $shape.height(),
          items: $shape.data("info") ? $shape.data("info").items : [],
        };
      }

      function fromObject(shape) {
        return $("<div>")
          .attr("id", shape.id)
          .addClass("shape")
          .css({
            top: `${shape.top}px`,
            left: `${shape.left}px`,
            width: `${shape.width}px`,
            height: `${shape.height}px`,
          })
          .data("info", { items: shape.items });
      }

      function saveShape(shape) {
        saveShapes(restoreShapes().concat(shape));
      }

      function saveShapes(shapes) {
        localStorage.setItem("shapes", JSON.stringify(shapes));
      }

      function restoreShapes() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shapes") ?? "[]");
      }

      function clearShapes() {
        return localStorage.clear("shapes");
      }

      function randInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>jQuery + localStorage</h1>
    <form name="add-shape">
      <textarea class="shape-input" name="shape" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
      <div class="actions">
        <button id="add-btn" type="submit">Add</button>
        <button id="clear-btn" type="button">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div class="shape-list"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```